# how do i remove signature info from my SAML response

Tags: lightning-apps, single-sign-on, connected-apps, saml

In SAML how do i sign only message without signing assertion? Is there any setting via setup?

if no is it possible to remove the < ds:Signature> info from < saml:Assertion> ??

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https://www.sampletest.com" ID="_fec3475b71b4aa42f541a4b0964f63d71490119342848" IssueInstant="2017-03-21T18:02:22.848Z" Version="2.0">
       <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://uat-netx360.my.salesforce.com</saml:Issuer>
       <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <ds:SignedInfo>
             <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
             <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
             <ds:Reference URI="#_fec3475b71b4aa42f541a4b0964f63d71490119342848">
                <ds:Transforms>
                   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                      <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds saml samlp xs xsi" />
                   </ds:Transform>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>rPNrFGjPDykaRsyqybdUWiDndhE=</ds:DigestValue>
             </ds:Reference>
          </ds:SignedInfo>
          <ds:SignatureValue>X/RO8H3o7sXNAQ5b7+vV8kmtjv4XU8CqS7kD/0yn/Acw/YkDSqmABg1Kx/Iiuz5TDDfL7igg9SNc
    X/AXhgSL+WLKNVpiJrnc+81rPrZonYW8EWtwdhLQZ4orYZu1Zmm5qQ7CWJVpj2heBxUQt0mhaQ81
    m6mSaqzUQ8JZ34WTAGoPn1kAgvj8619x/HIxPkT1hQnxg0sX4iIvItUF6PEsvFKtxZxU+m0Hyhsx
    1fZZGZT97yZWQ07NvFr2+ywh8uOM+v4Fz0+2EwRuiqsdmO0dqSWiHe/SQqM8Rb8QHR29xqSzFY44
    e4b7Q5QPeva+v8BT9P852rIFg0uqwEx3rRg9Iw==</ds:SignatureValue>
          <ds:KeyInfo>
             <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIErDCCA5SgAwIBAgIOAVhJQM+GAAAAAEgHchIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgZAxKDAmBgNVBAMM
    H1NlbGZTaWduZWRDZXJ0XzA5Tm92MjAxNl8xMzIyMTMxGDAWBgNVBAsMDzAwRDI4MDAwMDAwYkla
    UTEXMBUGA1UECgwOU2FsZXNmb3JjZS5jb20xFjAUBgNVBAcMDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28xCzAJBgNV
    BAgMAkNBMQwwCgYDVQQGEwNVU0EwHhcNMTYxMTA5MTMyMjE0WhcNMTcxMTA5MTIwMDAwWjCBkDEo
    MCYGA1UEAwwfU2VsZlNpZ25lZENlcnRfMDlOb3YyMDE2XzEzMjIxMzEYMBYGA1UECwwPMDBEMjgw
    MDAwMDBiSVpRMRcwFQYDVQQKDA5TYWxlc2ZvcmNlLmNvbTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNj
    bzELMAkGA1UECAwCQ0ExDDAKBgNVBAYTA1VTQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoC
    ggEBAI1RX8jJTk9wD8qBC9Tq+kEfUpqFkDDsLrZvvq/h0yO2ckdr/M8bVn0u5husBmrdcwjdsc0M
    pMG5/VQQkEGyYqlAl7oIOV6ufbNLcWMV0eyP4vFx9flgXBGgnd4vtpVLI5Z4eKqmNuqtCN59Xa1+
    L8PX4ETfSuwEcAauKJ8Dk9u1lQRRAfsUp78EZ8tK16bqmiCZiOr7qlV/KVlaB4fT8Wsq2q7yWFmW
    Dol5J8GgTFVjBPTlwzkj76rVwLjD3WISZh+i7osUw7CMM5YXsFly3V11zO7TWvFh11ZGecST0ypA
    j2BmzDGfVqA0ciQo42178R+RUNWI7AL+X5P/m8lK578CAwEAAaOCAQAwgf0wHQYDVR0OBBYEFLZg
    7xA7YzYkkMMk1KgIS0uZQHqaMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wgcoGA1UdIwSBwjCBv4AUtmDvEDtj
    NiSQwyTUqAhLS5lAepqhgZakgZMwgZAxKDAmBgNVBAMMH1NlbGZTaWduZWRDZXJ0XzA5Tm92MjAx
    Nl8xMzIyMTMxGDAWBgNVBAsMDzAwRDI4MDAwMDAwYklaUTEXMBUGA1UECgwOU2FsZXNmb3JjZS5j
    b20xFjAUBgNVBAcMDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28xCzAJBgNVBAgMAkNBMQwwCgYDVQQGEwNVU0GCDgFY
    SUDPhgAAAABIB3ISMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCKPFRWQOu9LhMLjOy18YLc0TaYdo5GvXld
    /lqiWkSsw0GN9sPKFO57lcnl1XU/BLXG6crfRyPgQqGydVwL2ovyzVk409xgc32bJBKr/ZgDq8pR
    XRnR0aVNxk0nofF9fbTYl1z1YUlVV4TAZ2IQ9mww/Nt6Bb0TwzLhNY3dzXGh076akb5QnQH1cmvm
    UUGrwI3M0GsgKDxEB7MGxYt2Pu3Yqw8a1zp/2CPsvOBocPLZAgwlTgGZTKl3nJhWM49vFwnPI6yV
    14H5n3hAnq7eZ7IT8WPCj6HOSsVS+81ZWOfu3IUxfLN8xuAoFGGYJWH+GJfAtW+PCx+PODCK1sqk
    bDkl</ds:X509Certificate>
             </ds:X509Data>
          </ds:KeyInfo>
       </ds:Signature>
       <samlp:Status>
          <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
       </samlp:Status>
       <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_bd89255be7d78b47184e965839d646691490119342848" IssueInstant="2017-03-21T18:02:22.848Z" Version="2.0">
          <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://my.salesforce.com</saml:Issuer>
          <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
             <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
                <ds:Reference URI="#_bd89255be7d78b47184e965839d646691490119342848">
                   <ds:Transforms>
                      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                         <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds saml xs xsi" />
                      </ds:Transform>
                   </ds:Transforms>
                   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                   <ds:DigestValue>zAjePWIU3Eq0/1qp5Yf+nPocxiM=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
             </ds:SignedInfo>
             <ds:SignatureValue>WAmUaK+epUZJ3Twwf9iy0Xn8djSs90amjSo627Jtrr/c7uaEDxit9J7vnr1AXYuBem0uraOxQorR
    t7lCu98Pa00nc3Qx9x574IhbIjSG0TK1gYFd9UxnRfUARG4sGvT9W/0WjChj6R2tVccbcI96CovP
    MaJ3EHHRwDETzHYFYm8Ces1aHkRwkOtCwn0bqQP/KQ5dHpQm9Mog12MkxIxB7LX68piU8qS8a2cv
    YTL2I8uXyMjFdbn/undOwl+2Dc5WBqaI4sYxV97STJJn40ipxLOJnUNnX5NQEEKEdpGX1ivfU3nZ
    747xciE+vs4O18Mmy+MDmEZpXlCWEfnwoxAO+g==</ds:SignatureValue>
             <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                   <ds:X509Certificate>MIIErDCCA5SgAwIBAgIOAVhJQM+GAAAAAEgHchIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgZAxKDAmBgNVBAMM
    H1NlbGZTaWduZWRDZXJ0XzA5Tm92MjAxNl8xMzIyMTMxGDAWBgNVBAsMDzAwRDI4MDAwMDAwYkla
    UTEXMBUGA1UECgwOU2FsZXNmb3JjZS5jb20xFjAUBgNVBAcMDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28xCzAJBgNV
    BAgMAkNBMQwwCgYDVQQGEwNVU0EwHhcNMTYxMTA5MTMyMjE0WhcNMTcxMTA5MTIwMDAwWjCBkDEo
    MCYGA1UEAwwfU2VsZlNpZ25lZENlcnRfMDlOb3YyMDE2XzEzMjIxMzEYMBYGA1UECwwPMDBEMjgw
    MDAwMDBiSVpRMRcwFQYDVQQKDA5TYWxlc2ZvcmNlLmNvbTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNU2FuIEZyYW5jaXNj
    bzELMAkGA1UECAwCQ0ExDDAKBgNVBAYTA1VTQTCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoC
    ggEBAI1RX8jJTk9wD8qBC9Tq+kEfUpqFkDDsLrZvvq/h0yO2ckdr/M8bVn0u5husBmrdcwjdsc0M
    pMG5/VQQkEGyYqlAl7oIOV6ufbNLcWMV0eyP4vFx9flgXBGgnd4vtpVLI5Z4eKqmNuqtCN59Xa1+
    L8PX4ETfSuwEcAauKJ8Dk9u1lQRRAfsUp78EZ8tK16bqmiCZiOr7qlV/KVlaB4fT8Wsq2q7yWFmW
    Dol5J8GgTFVjBPTlwzkj76rVwLjD3WISZh+i7osUw7CMM5YXsFly3V11zO7TWvFh11ZGecST0ypA
    j2BmzDGfVqA0ciQo42178R+RUNWI7AL+X5P/m8lK578CAwEAAaOCAQAwgf0wHQYDVR0OBBYEFLZg
    7xA7YzYkkMMk1KgIS0uZQHqaMA8GA1UdEwEB/wQFMAMBAf8wgcoGA1UdIwSBwjCBv4AUtmDvEDtj
    NiSQwyTUqAhLS5lAepqhgZakgZMwgZAxKDAmBgNVBAMMH1NlbGZTaWduZWRDZXJ0XzA5Tm92MjAx
    Nl8xMzIyMTMxGDAWBgNVBAsMDzAwRDI4MDAwMDAwYklaUTEXMBUGA1UECgwOU2FsZXNmb3JjZS5j
    b20xFjAUBgNVBAcMDVNhbiBGcmFuY2lzY28xCzAJBgNVBAgMAkNBMQwwCgYDVQQGEwNVU0GCDgFY
    SUDPhgAAAABIB3ISMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCKPFRWQOu9LhMLjOy18YLc0TaYdo5GvXld
    /lqiWkSsw0GN9sPKFO57lcnl1XU/BLXG6crfRyPgQqGydVwL2ovyzVk409xgc32bJBKr/ZgDq8pR
    XRnR0aVNxk0nofF9fbTYl1z1YUlVV4TAZ2IQ9mww/Nt6Bb0TwzLhNY3dzXGh076akb5QnQH1cmvm
    UUGrwI3M0GsgKDxEB7MGxYt2Pu3Yqw8a1zp/2CPsvOBocPLZAgwlTgGZTKl3nJhWM49vFwnPI6yV
    14H5n3hAnq7eZ7IT8WPCj6HOSsVS+81ZWOfu3IUxfLN8xuAoFGGYJWH+GJfAtW+PCx+PODCK1sqk
    bDkl</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
             </ds:KeyInfo>
          </ds:Signature>
          <saml:Subject>
             <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">16e9e30adc36a98b549a8e8be486df01831205ebb92b6c21baa97ca975efccba</saml:NameID>
             <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2017-03-21T18:07:22.848Z" Recipient="https://www.sampletest.com" />
             </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
          </saml:Subject>
          <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2017-03-21T18:01:52.848Z" NotOnOrAfter="2017-03-21T18:07:22.848Z">
             <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>www.sampletest.com</saml:Audience>
             </saml:AudienceRestriction>
          </saml:Conditions>
          <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2017-03-21T18:02:22.848Z">
             <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
             </saml:AuthnContext>
          </saml:AuthnStatement>
          <saml:AttributeStatement>
             <saml:Attribute Name="userId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">00528000005ELus</saml:AttributeValue>
             </saml:Attribute>
             <saml:Attribute Name="username" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">XXXXXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
             </saml:Attribute>
             <saml:Attribute Name="email" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">XXXXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
             </saml:Attribute>
             <saml:Attribute Name="is_portal_user" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">false</saml:AttributeValue>
             </saml:Attribute>
             <saml:Attribute Name="AccountNum" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType" />
             </saml:Attribute>
             <saml:Attribute Name="CustId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">XXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
             </saml:Attribute>
             <saml:Attribute Name="selection" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:anyType">XXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
             </saml:Attribute>
          </saml:AttributeStatement>
       </saml:Assertion>
    </samlp:Response>
```

i could see that the example in this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_about.htm&type=0&language=en_US) doesnt have the < ds:signature> in the < saml:Assertion> how can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now salesforce doesnt have any setting where you could chose what type of samlresponse you need via connected app. But its possible by generating signed XML using apex

samples :

1.https://github.com/salesforceidentity/saml-idp

2.https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wSGIAY

Comment: What you're attempting to do should not be done at all. SAML specification requires a signature at either assertion or response level. Having a signature on both assertion and response is completely ok. There will be no discernible difference in terms of performance with. Writing your own identity provider (even if possible in ApEx) is a bad idea. It's going to penalize you forever because you'll be reinventing a wheel (more like reinventing a piece of the engine)

Comment: Yea true I'm not implementing it!! I'm just sharing the info which I got from salesforce community..